# Vue one component per page

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components

What are the problems/downsides to only having one component per page, where the entire page is in?

My elaboration: I have a sidebar in a separate component that's persistent troughout the entire application. The rest of the page is all in one component. It works, it's fast enough, and it functions the way I want it to.

I've since learned that most web applications use one object per component and import it to the page component to make it more readable and reusable. I don't reuse any code (apart from the sidebar which is already in it's own component). Is there any downside from writing the application this way, other than readability of the code? Is there any potential benefit in refactoring it?

Comment: Every app is a little different. If you've got a lot of duplicate code, you can always start by making components to reduce that duplication. e.g. if you built a `<date-picker/>` that you use in 50 places, make it a component. But if all your pages are completely different, IMHO it's just a judgment call really as to whether to break out parts into separate components. If it makes your code more readable and easier to maintain, go for it. If not, it's probably fine as is.

Comment: @David784 It will probably make it a little bit more readable, but not much. Judging from your answer (unless I get different responses after this), it seems like it won't be worth the effort to refactor it. Thanks!

Comment: Motto of my development life: Build it like it will be 500% more complex in 1 year and you won't be the one maintaining it.